# Adding Spinner Dynamically On Item Selected LIstner IllegalStateException specified child already has a parent

Tags: java, android, events, dynamic, spinner

I'm adding a `Spinner` dynamically on item selected my code is:

```
final Spinner[] sp = new Spinner[10];
for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    sp[a] = new Spinner(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    para.leftMargin = 300;
    para.topMargin = 100;
    ArrayAdapter < String > spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, value);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp[a].setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    sp[a].setLayoutParams(para);
    sp[a].setTag(a);
    layout.addView(sp[a]);


    sp[a].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1,
        int pos, long arg3) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_questiondynamic);
            String[] DDvalue = GetDropDownvalue(Avalue);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MultiQuesRelaLayOut);
            final Spinner[] Sp = new Spinner[10];
            int add = (int) arg0.getTag();
            Sp[add] = new Spinner(com.example.hakslogin.QuestionActivityDynamic.this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.leftMargin = 25;
            param.topMargin = 200;
            Sp[add].setId(add);
            Sp[add].setLayoutParams(param);
            ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (com.example.hakslogin.QuestionActivityDynamic.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DDvalue);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Sp[add].setAdapter(adapter);
            if (add == 0) {
                layout.addView(sp[add]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

This code is written in `onCreate` method. In this code I am dynamically adding spinner two times and also creating spinner event onItemSelected for creating another Spinner in this event as shown in code.

In first spinner "value" variable is array and it has values. It is working fine.

In line `String[] DDvalue = GetDropDownvalue(Avalue);`it is getting value from method and will fill it in spinner. It is working fine.

When I create its event and create dynamic spinner in this event cause error "IllegalStateException" on line

```
 layout.addView(sp[add]);
```

I tried to write in detail with code. Hope everything is clear.

Hopes for your suggestion.

EDIT:

i got error `layout.addView(sp[add]);`. I replace it with layout.addView(Sp[add]);

Comment: maybe cause youre calling 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_questiondynamic);' in onItemSelected and after this 'layout' no longer exists. And please dont use variable names like sp and Sp.

Comment: /2marilion i think so let me check this